# I found the inconsistency data on postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of datas on postgres. This table, called it 'table1', have a unique constraint on field 'id'. this table also have 3 other fields, 'write_date', 'state', 'state_detail'.

all this time, i got no problem when accesing and joining these table with another table with field 'id' as the relational field. but, this time, i got a strange result when i querying this table1.

when i run this query (called it Query1):

```
SELECT id, write_date, state, state_detail
FROM table1
WHERE write_date = '2019-07-30 19:42:49.314' or write_date = '2019-07-30 14:29:06.945'
```

it gives me 2 rows of datas, with the same id, but different value for the other fields:

```
id     ||         write_date        || state || state_detail

168972      2019-07-30 14:29:06.945      1           80
168972      2019-07-30 19:42:49.314      2          120
```

BUT, when i run this query (called it Query2):

```
SELECT id, write_date, state, state_detail
FROM table1
WHERE id = 168972
```

it gives me just 1 row:

```
id     ||         write_date        || state || state_detail
168972      2019-07-30 19:42:49.314      2          120
```

How come it gives the different result. i mean, i checked 'table1', it has the unique constraint 'id' as primary key. But, how come this happened?

i have restart the postgres service, and i run those 2 queries again. And it still gives me the same result as above.

Comment: What's the datatype of  `id`?

Comment: What is your exact Postgres version (`select version()` will tell you). Some older versions did have a bug where unique indexes got corrupted, but they have all been fix by now. Does `reindex table1` change this?

Comment: @KaushikNayak column 'id' is integer type.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, this happened when i use postgres8.4. i havent do reindex table1, bcs i think, table1 just only has 1 data with id 168972. so this doesnt violate the unique constraint for 'id'. the one that made me confused is.., when i select or joining those row data id=168972 with another table (say it 'table2', suppose it has just 1 row data) on column table1.id = table2.tbl1_id, it gives me 2 datas with different detail..

Comment: 8.4 has been unsupported for [5 years now](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). You shouldn't be using that version any more. If this is indeed caused by a bug in Postgres there is no way you will ever get a fix for that bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a case of index corruption, specifically on the unique index on the id column. Could you run the following query:

```
SELECT ctid, id, write_date, state, state_detail FROM table1
WHERE write_date = '2019-07-30 19:42:49.314' or write_date = '2019-07-30 14:29:06.945'
```

You will likely receive 2 rows back for the id, with two different ctids. The ctid represents the physical location on disk for each row. Presuming you get two rows back, you will need to pick a row and delete the other one in order to "fix" the data. In addition, you'll want to recreate the unique index on the table, in order to prevent this from happening again.

Oh, and don't be surprised if you find other rows in the table like this. Depending on the source of the corruption (bad disks, bad memory, recent crash, upgrade to glibc?), this could be the sign of future trouble to come. I'd probably double-check all my tables for any issues, recreate any unique indexes, and look at the OS level for any signs of disk corruption or I/O errors. And if you aren't on the latest version of Postgres, you should upgrade.

Comment: thanks @xzilla, this help me alot. now i can delete the data which is unused, and fixing the unique constraint.